# How to design Appengine Search API Index for shared documents?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, search

I'm trying to design a good schema for use with the AppEngine Search API (java) and would love some opinions given the following use case:

In our applications, we want users to be able to search for objects of type Foo. A Foo object looks like:

```
{
    groupId: "x1",
    name: "somename"
    someFieldA: "somevalue",
    someFieldB: "somevalue",
    someFieldC: "somevalue"
}
```

However,  a different Foo object could look like:

```
{
    groupId: "x2",
    name: "somename"
    someFieldD: "somevalue",
    someFieldE: "somevalue",
    someFieldF: "somevalue"
}
```

**The group id's are important:**

- the groupId field determines what properties each Foo object has
  (i.e. someFieldA, someFieldB, someFieldC only exist for Foo's with a
  groupId of X1)
- each user only has access to Foo's with a certain group id

So, the use case I want to solve is that a user should be able to search for Foo's (by any of its fields) given that they only have access to certain Foo's. Here are two solutions that both have drawbacks:

**Solution 1:**

- Create 1 index for all Foo's.
- The fields of this index are the SUPERSET of every field in every Foo.
- This works great because a users search can be translated to: `userquery AND (groupId:X OR groupId:Y OR groupId:Z)`
- its also good because all Foo's regardless or their groupId are ranked and sorted relative to each other.
- **I don't think approach works though**, because there is a 1000 field limit on every schema, and there could be enough groupids such that the superset of all the fields of all the Foo's is more than 1000 fields

**Solution 2:**

- create 1 index **per groupId**
- a users search is there for translated into async searches (1 per groupid that the user has access to) and then the results must be combined
- this has the benefit that we won't run into the 1000 field limit
- one downside is that this potentially costs more as you're doing more than 1 query to the search api
- the more important downside is there does not seem to be an easy way to combine the results of each individual query. If each of the queries returns results, the score for each returned document is normalized to all the results in that query, so how would you combine results from different queries?

It seems like solution 2 is most ideal - but I can't figure out how to get around the combining/ranking of the results issue.

**Any ideas?**

**--UPDATE 1--**

Here are some more concrete examples of what the documents would look like:

```
{
    groupId:"Hiring Process",
    name: "Bob Smith",
    position: "Software Engineer",
    yearsOfExperience: 6
}

{
    groupId:"Sales Process",
    name: "Frank J",
    company: "Engineering Engineer Inc.",
    contactInfo: "555-555-5555"
}

{
    groupId:"Hiring Process",
    name: "Jane Doe",
    position: "Marketing",
    yearsOfExperience: 3
}

{
    groupId:"Sales Process",
    name: "Jane Moe",
    company: "Google",
    contactInfo: "666-666-6666"
}
```

As you can see above, these documents represent people. Each object either has a group id of "Sales Process" or "Hiring Process". Notice that the fields of the document are different based on which groupId they have. A single user in our system has access to all of the information about all of the people in both processes.

So lets say our user does a search for `engineer`, that should return 2 results, 1 for `Bob Smith` and one for `Frank J`. However, the `Frank J` result should be ranked/scored higher because the word "engineer" appears twice in the document.

Because the superset of the number of fields of all the documents may have a size >1000, I don't think I can put all the documents in 1 index. If I shard the indexes (1 per group id), how do I rank/score across several sets of search results?

**--UPDATE 2--*

The reason that we would exceed the 1000 field limit is because the schema of Foo objects are user configurable. So for example, a user could create a groupId called "Sales Process" and add a few user defined fields like "lead source", "product interested in", "close date", etc.

Because each user can customize their groups, across millions of users, the superset of all fields is definitely >1000. The example Foo objects listed above are a little simplistic. The groupId is actually an Id pointing to a user created schema of all the custom fields they want. And the foo objects actually contain the values for those fields.

Comment: How about Solution 1 plus grouping all of the non searchable fields into a json / xml / whatever format. You can persist the result as a single text field (say -- content). You can parse the content easy on the java side, and will not have to deal with 1000 fields or a long list of separate indexes.

Comment: I want all the fields to be searchable so that doesn't work very well.

Comment: In separate? Or a full text search over them would work?

Comment: In seperate. I want to be able to do a query like "somefieldA:X name:Y" as well as "X Y"

Comment: So I guess you are out of lucky, if you want to stick with this API you will need to pay the extra cost of querying several indexes, merge the resulting collections on your application, plus sort and normalize scores manually. Actually, my advice is, whatever you are trying to do, stop and find a better solution (for example, set up a Solr instance with dynamic fields retrieved as a Map, or even think about something other than a search engine to solve your problem).

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on the meaning of the fields, so it's easier to understand your index design?

Comment: Can you also elaborate on why you end up having more than 1000 different attributes on those 'people' documents?

Comment: @proppy updated the question - see update 2

Answer (score 2):

Here's a half-baked "answer".  My hope is that it may stimulate your thinking enough for you to come up with a real answer that will work well enough.

To me, the notion that the schema (i.e., set of field names) is defined dynamically based on user input is a red flag.  I might be reluctant to go so far as to make a blanket statement that one should *never* do such a thing.  But it certainly seems to be something worthy of a second thought.

If the fields are user-defined, it would seem to follow that there can be no specific processing knowledge that the system can bring to bear on them.  In other words, to the system the fields must simply be generic information containers.  Would you agree?

So, my thinking would go in the direction of eliminating that aspect of it, one way or another.

I wonder if there's a way you could make the actual field names generic (e.g., UserField1, UserField2, etc.), and store elsewhere the per-groupId mapping of user-provided field names to actual field names.  It seems as if that would work fine for global searches (where the search query doesn't mention a field name).

I do recognize that users would then not be able to simply write a query like [engineer yearsOfExperience>3].  But, come to think of it, could they do that anyway?  Do you allow them to define the types of the user-defined fields?

Anyway, the sense I have is that these "fields" are factored inappropriately.  Somehow the user-defined field names want to be stored as data, not used as dynamic schema.

Comment: thanks for your thoughts. You are correct they are generic info containers, however they are typed (by the user). The schema for these custom fields is not actually dynamic schema when stored in the datastore - it is stored as data as you suggest. However, for the purposes of *search*, we'd like them to be different fields so users can search for them directly as you mentioned (yearsOfExperience>3).

Comment: another way to think about it is, say gmail wanted to support adding metadata to emails. Specifically, say a user could add key value pairs to any email thread like "Importance: 3" or "Due Date: Nov 5, 2013". Now suppose gmail wanted to let you search across those metadata fields, how would they design their indexes?

Comment: @aloo why not creating 1 schema per user then?

Comment: @proppy because each users index could still have >1000 fields